# What does "gracefully stop" mean?

Tags: docker

I'm trying out **Docker** and came across 
`docker container stop <hash>           # Gracefully stop the specified container`

I'm not asking about the difference between docker stop and docker kill. I'm wondering about the term **"gracefully"**

> What does "gracefully stop" mean in this context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which one should i use? docker kill or docker stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339469/which-one-should-i-use-docker-kill-or-docker-stop)

Comment: @atline That's not my question. BTW, I read that one too. That one is about the difference between kill and stop.  Mine is about the meaning of "gracefully"  :)

Comment: As the answer says, "gracefully" means `SIGTERM` is being sent, otherwise it's `SIGKILL`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is related to the difference between `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`.

**SIGTERM:** When a process receives this signal, it has the chance to perform cleanup. That's the so-called "graceful" exit; it corresponds to `docker stop`.

**SIGKILL:** The process doesn't even know it has received this signal and it has no chance to ignore or do anything about it. The process directly exits. That's the so-called "not graceful" exit; it corresponds to `docker kill`.

For further details look at [this topic](https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/).

Comment: Additional: By stopping a container Docker send a `SIGTERM` to the container. I the container have not stopped in a timeout period the signal `SIGKILL` will be send. In other words: using `stop` Docker will first try to stop polite (graceful) the container.

Comment: It's also worth reading [the importance of PID1](https://tandrepires.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/the-importance-of-pid-1-in-containers/).
`SIGTERM` will get sent to PID1. If the main process is not on PID1, it will not receive the signal and will not be able to be gracefully stopped.